# Unit test case incase of no output channel for my Integration flow

Tags: spring-integration

I have only one handle() and then get(), no output channel. On sending the message to this handle getting the Object I am sending back in flow. But in unit test I am getting back boolean value. How to get the expected object back in unit testing also?

below is code unit test.

In Unit test - boolean value is coming on sending the message instead of expected object

Object o = this.acknowledgeAlarmInputChannel.send(message);
  System.out.println("output: " + o); // printing boolean value true
Code:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow acknowledgeAlarmGatewayFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("acknowledgeAlarmInputChannel")
            .handle(this::createAlarmAckEvent)
            .get();
}
```

Unit test:

```
@Test
public void testEvent() {
    String expectedEMResponse = "{\n" +
            "  \"data\": {\n" +
            "    \"id\": 19,\n" +
            "    \"type\": \"alarms\",\n" +
            "    \"attributes\": {}\n" +
            "  }\n" +
            "}";
    MessageHandler mockMessageHandler = mock(MessageHandler.class);
    this.acknowledgeAlarmInputChannel.subscribe(mockMessageHandler);

    MockRestServiceServer server = MockRestServiceServer.bindTo(restTemplate).build();
    server.expect(requestTo(emAcknowledgeEventUrl.replace("{hostID}", "12")))
            .andRespond(withSuccess(expectedEMResponse, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

    AlarmInstance alarmInstance = new AlarmInstance();
    alarmInstance.setAlarmName("a1");
    alarmInstance.setInstanceId("1");
    alarmInstance.setAcknowledgedAt(new Date());
    alarmInstance.setAcknowledgedBy("u1");
    alarmInstance.setComponentName("x1");
    GenericMessage<AlarmInstance> message = new GenericMessage<AlarmInstance>(alarmInstance);

    Object o = this.acknowledgeAlarmInputChannel.send(message);
    System.out.println("output: " + o);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `mockMessageHandler` stuff - that will just subscribe a second (no-op) handler to the channel.

```
QueueChannel replies = new QueueChannel();
Message<AlarmInstance> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(alarmInstance)
    .setReplyChannel(replies)
    .build();
this.acknowledgeAlarmInputChannel.send(message);
Message<?> reply = replies.get(0);
assertNotNull(reply);
...
```

Or, use a `MessagingTemplate` (`sendAndReceive` or `convertSendAndReceive` operation).

Comment: Accepted it, thank you Gary for the process explanation.